# Can't pass param when redirect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my spring boot app I want to pass param `errorMessage` when user is admin.

snippet:

```
@Controller
public class UsersController {
  @GetMapping("/users")
    public String getAllUsers(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        logger.info("getAllUsers: model = " + model + ", redirectAttributes= " + redirectAttributes);
        Set<Role> roleSet = new HashSet<>();
        roleSet.add(Role.ADMIN);
        adminsList = userRepository.findAllByRolesIn(roleSet);
        model.addAttribute("usersList", userRepository.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("adminsList", adminsList);
        model.addAttribute("appName", appName);
        return "users";
    }

    @RequestMapping("user/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") int id, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        logger.info("user_id_to_delete = " + id);
        Optional<User> userAdmin = adminsList.stream()
                .filter(user -> user.getId() == id)
                .findFirst();
        if (userAdmin.isPresent() && adminsList.size() == 1) {
            String errorMessage = "In system must have at least one administrator";
            logger.error(errorMessage);
            redirectAttributes.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        } else {
            userRepository.deleteById(id);
        }
        return "redirect:/users";
    }
```

after try to delete user (method `deleteUser`)  success call

```
redirectAttributes.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
```

And after that success call method `getAllUsers`. But param `redirectAttributes` is empty.

Comment: You should get the `errorMessage` in the model of getAllUsers() after the redirect

Comment: @R.G yes, I got it from model. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the api [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

> A RedirectAttributes model is empty when the method is called and is
>   never used unless the method returns a redirect view name or a
>   RedirectView.
>
> After the redirect, attributes are automatically added to the model of
>   the controller that serves the target URL.

The `errorMessage` will be available in the model of `getAllUsers()` after the redirect .